# IntelliJ shortcut for inserting a null check?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, code-completion

Is there a shortcut for inserting the code:

```
if (someParameter == null)
   throw NullPointerException("someParameter is null");
```

Comment: I would recommend an IllegalArgumentException instead if this is for checking paramters.

Comment: @Thor - Let's not turn this into another discussion - for now, I'm simply interesting in the IntelliJ shortcut, if it exists, not in the type of exception thrown.

Answer (score 30):

Try typing `ifn` followed by Tab. You can find more of those or define your own by going to the preferences and searching for "Live Templates".

Comment: The organization of the Live Templates can be confusing.  In my installation, there are around 30 categories. The "ifn" template is listed under the "other" category.

Answer (score 15):

IntelliJ IDEA provides another functionality, similar to shortcuts, that can help with your productivity, namely, **Postfix completion**.

If you want to insert a null check, type '.null' after the variable name, e.g.

[image: postfix completion]

and the null-checking code will be inserted automatically, e.g.

[image: null checking code]

IntelliJ IDEA provides more handy postfix completions, which you can find in Preferences at **Editor > General > Postfix Completion**

[image: Postfix Completion]

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a template defined for that but you can easily create one. Just follow the steps described [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/03/defining-a-live-template-for-null-check/).

Answer (score 3):

There is now an easy way to do it (in version 13.1), described here:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with having some annotations in your code then you could try the solution mentioned [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html). It does not solve the problem directly but if you have this kind of null checks at many places you can use this :)

Comment: Link in answer is dead (*"Error 404"*).